# Ubuntu: trouble setting up Mail Server

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I was follwing the Guid @ http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.10. But I ran into some issues.

the first issue was: (mail.log)

```
Jan 19 21:52:07 ... imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
Jan 19 21:52:07 ... imapd: chdir example.eu/jan/: No such file or directory
Jan 19 21:52:07 ... imapd: jan@example.eu: No such file or directory
```

After a while of googling I found out that the folders are initialy created when I receive my first mail. -> So I sent one: (mail.log)

```
Jan 19 21:55:51 ... postfix/smtpd[1315]: connect from mx1.uni-trier.de[136.199.224.17]
Jan 19 21:55:51 ... postfix/trivial-rewrite[1278]: warning: do not list domain example.eu in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jan 19 21:55:51 ... postfix/smtpd[1315]: C0A1C231808A: client=mx1.uni-trier.de[136.199.224.17]
Jan 19 21:55:51 ... postfix/cleanup[1318]: C0A1C231808A: message-id=<964FCDEF-1A79-4EE0-A81C-4F8C34E28FEB@uni-trier.de>
Jan 19 21:55:51 ... postfix/qmgr[1177]: C0A1C231808A: from=<prvs=724bee520=XXX@uni-trier.de>, size=1179, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

For me it looks like the mail-server is receiving my mail but the sending account tells me:

```
I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below[...]
```

Do you have any idea why? I did it exactly the guide way.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

- /etc/postfix/main.cf @ http://pastebin.com/1AwEwzT3
- Courier Config
  can be found here:
  http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.10-p2

Comment: Please add /etc/postfix/main.cf and related courier configuration files.

Comment: Is there any `/home/vmail/<username>` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `main.cf`, modify line 34, remove `example.eu`. Restart postfix
2. Is there any /home/vmail/ directory?
3. On the email server, does following command successfully delivery a email to the user?

   ```
   mail <username>
   ```

   Or step 14 on P4 of your link http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-12.10-p4
4. Line 43, potential error in tutorial

   ```
   virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
   ```

   Shoule be

   ```
   virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
   ```
5. Create Maildir manually

   ```
   mkdir /home/vmail/<username>
   maildirmake /home/vmail/<username>/Maildir
   chown -R 5000:5000 /home/vmail/<username>
   ```

Comment: 1. I removed it <br> 2. No there is nothing :( 3. I tryed strep 14. And the mail.log output is the following: http://pastebin.com/prEGpniv --- thanks for your help!

Comment: `mail for mail.example.eu loops back to myself` is the problem, I have to go through your `main.cf` again.

Comment: (1) Check 4 in answer. (2) Do you already have that user in mysql database?

Comment: (1) checked. (2) Yes there are. and the Mailserver MX-Record: domain.eu ... still bouncing :( Any other idea?

Comment: Try 5 in answer.

Comment: (5) check - After I logged in (squrrel-mail as stated in the Guide) -> http://pastebin.com/JY30efUM and blank page. Can I contact you in skype or somewhat? Would be great... Because I am getting nuts. I am googling all day everyday and nothing seems to work out. I am finde if you resign. Thank mate.